# How to remove border from dropdown tab in bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4, navbar

using Bootstrap 4, I cannot seem to get rid of this border when selecting the drop-down tab.

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lo1qd.png)

[Inspector View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyR5q.png)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPgOk.png)

Comment: Do not use images, please post your code and test cases here as well as your CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this style, this is not border, but outline that comes on focus and active anchors

```
a#navbarDropdown.nav-link.dropdown-toggle:active,
a#navbarDropdown.nav-link.dropdown-toggle:focus {
   outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: it's on found it. there was no : after outline

Comment: Sorry typo at my end

Comment: I'm new to this if you could help me with how to do that I'd be happy too. There is a lot I cannot do because I'm a new user.

Comment: You can accept an answer even if you are a new user, Read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: All done. do you have a twitter? I'd like to be able to message you for help and advice from time to time if you'd be happy to help me with that?

Comment: You can message me on SO itself. Just comment below my answer and i will get a notification

Comment: Do I need to just come back to this post? When I have a question or should I just create a new post when I have a new issue?

Comment: you should create a new post and just to let me know, add the link to that post here :) i will try my best to help if i can

Comment: Hi Nandita, I've got another issue but cannot see what is happening.

Comment: post it on SO and send me the link here. i will see if i can help you out

Comment: <!-- FULL BOX -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="fullbox">
                <h2>plumbing</h2>
            </div>     
        </div>       
    </div>

    <!-- FULL BOX END -->

Comment: /* --------------------------  FULL BOX  -------------------------- */

.fullbox {
    border: 1px solid orange;
    background-image: url(/images/topimage.jpg) no-repeat;
}

/* --------------------------  END  -------------------------- */

Comment: Please post a new question, I cant help you like this!

Comment: When I'm trying to post a question it won't let me says this is already a question. then other errors appear.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51223192/adding-background-image-using-css-not-working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51247236/nav-dropdown-hover-using-bootstrap-4 new question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51251434/how-to-remove-underline-and-text-hover-from-bootstrap-4 another question?

Comment: I have removed the `.toggle` class from my dropdown (client asked for it!) so I had to use `.nav-item.dropdown .nav-link:active, .nav-item.dropdown .nav-link:focus` instead.