# adding background image using css, not working?

Tags: html, css

I've included code from the index.html and style.css pages are linked correctly as other elements are all working fine.

```css
.fullbox {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  background-image: url(background-image:url(/images/topmain.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="fullbox">
      <h2>plumbing</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages in Developer tools? Are you sure the URL to the image is correct?

Comment: you did somehow a bad copy/paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have mistaken CSS here**

```
background-image: url(background-image:url(/images/topmain.jpg) no-repeat;
```

**It should be**

```
background-image: url('images/topmain.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

OR

```
background: url(/images/topmain.jpg) no-repeat;
```

**Update in your snippet**

```css
.fullbox {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  background-image: url('images/topmain.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="fullbox">
      <h2>plumbing</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Another live example**

```css
.fullbox {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  background-image: url('https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/1928643/avatars/small/b3f1a5ea4d68ff539b8f808ff3c4b8a5.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="fullbox">
      <h2>plumbing</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**To learn more about background-image property and path**

- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Comment: Embarrassing Mistake.

Answer (score 0):

background: url(/images/topmain.jpg) no-repeat;
}

Answer (score 0):

`background: url(source/...) center center/cover no-repeat fixed;`1)you can not use no-repeat in background-image , instead you should use JUST background syntax. e.g 
2) after url no need to write background-image again, you can just go ahead and give your relative address , e.g `background-image: url(source/...)`
hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's was helpful.