# Nav dropdown hover using Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I currently have a navbar I've made using Bootstrap 4, I was hoping someone could help me. I cannot get the dropdown to show on hover. At the moment it only works when the tab is clicked then the dropdown menu show.

I would like to know how to make the dropdown menu hover?

```css
a.dropdown-item:hover {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px grey;
}


/* Removing outline from navbar tabs */

a#navbarDropdown.nav-link.dropdown-toggle:active,
a#navbarDropdown.nav-link.dropdown-toggle:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">Heating</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">item 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">item 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">item 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">item 1</a>
      </div>
    </li>
</div>
```

I need some help just making the dropdown work on hover rather than having to click for dropdown.

I've tried to add data-hover="dropdown".

Answer (score -1):

```css
.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

Figured it out.