# how to remove underline and text hover from bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css

I'm using Bootstrap 4, when I'm using rows and creating columns the text automatically has this overlay text where there is an, underline and a hover   how can I remove this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add 
text-decoration:none on the element on which the underline is coming...

for removing underline on hover, add style like this

> a:hover{  text-decoration:none; }

Comment: thanks for the reply, what I was looking for was a way to stop it from happening unless I wanted it to. The code that worked for me was a:hover i, a, i{
  text-decoration:none !important;
}

Comment: I still voted and ticked it for you. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I needed to do to remove it and stop it from happening.

```css
a:hover i,
a,
i {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```